# Regex for leading Characters

Tags: regex

I have a textbox to accept string.
I want to put a validation in that like, if character `X` is there in string it should be at last, not in the middle. But `X` can repeat many times. A string may have 5 `X` or 10 `X`, but all `X` must be at last not in the middle of string.

For e.g.:

`testingxxxx`  This is correct string because all `X` are at last.

`test_x_ingxxxxx` This is Invalid because `X` is in between the string.

`testX` This is Valid because `X` at last

`XtestXXXX` This is Invalid because `X` at starting position.

Comment: What language are you going to use for this task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[^Xx]+[Xx]*$
```

It first matches everything but `X` or `x` one or more times, and then it matches `X` or `x` zero to infinite times.

Demo: http://www.regexr.com/3b32s

Comment: This does not match `abc` or `XXX`, where both are correct.

Comment: @Dorus it does match `abc`,  and `XXX` starts with an X so it is invalid

Comment: @bigOTHER: Where does it say `X` can not be at the start?

Comment: @moffeltje @Dorus OP doesnt clarify it , sure all `X` are at the end but it starts too with `X`. so its up to OP if he accept zero-length string after ignoring all 'X'

Comment: @Dorus Last case in question: XtestXXXX This is Invalid because X at starting position.

Comment: @bigOTHER I read that as invalid because there are non-x charchers after the first X. But you are right, could be that the OP meant that the string cannot start empty ignoring the x.

Answer (score 1):

Since no hint has been provided about the programming language used, I will try to use a general purpose regular expression that matches *any character except x (X)* at the beginning of the line that ends with *one or more x (X) characters*:

```
^[^Xx]*([Xx]+)$
```

- `^[^Xx]*`: Any sequence of characters (digits) at beginning of the line that is not either upper or lower case *x*
- `([Xx]+)$`: The line must end with a sequence of one or more *x* characters (upper or lower case). Note the capturing group use here `(...)` in order to capture your tail string which I supposed to be subject of search.

[Here you can give it an online test.](https://regex101.com/r/zO0bP8/3).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[^xX]*[xX]*$
```

First match all none (x or X) characters, then match all trailing (x or X) characters.

Alternative, you can limit the number of x's at the end to 5 or 10:

```
^[^xX]*([xX]{5}){0,2}$
```

However, that does not match with your example of `testingxxxx` (4 times x) and `testX` (only one times x).

Comment: This would match `XXX` which is invalid because it starts with a `X`

Comment: @moffeltje Please quote me the part of the question where it say it is invalid to start with a `X`.

Comment: " `XtestXXXX` This is Invalid because X at starting position."

Comment: But this wont match `XtestXXXX`.

Comment: But that's just an example of an invalid string, to indicate that the case of an `X` at the start is invalid.